# Manually removing level from legend while retaining levels not present in data

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have data I am plotting in a divergent bar plot using ggplot2.  It is actually an interactive plot where the user can choose the factor they are looking at.  The levels go from strongly disagree to strongly agree.  Sometimes, as in this minimal example, not all levels are present.  Even so, I still want to present all possible values in the legend so as to not mislead the user.

I figured out the way to do this within scale_fill_manual was to use limits (rather than breaks) to specify the levels.

The problem is, being a divergent bar plot I have had to hack the data a bit to get "no opinion" straddling zero.  You will see I have "no opinion" and "no opinion2".  In this example, 12% of respondents had no opinion, and this has been split into "no opinion" = 6 and "no opinion2" = -6.

The result is that "no opinion2" pops up in the legend, and I would like to remove it.

Just to reiterate, if I were to use "breaks" rather than "limits" in scale_fill_manual, I would not get all factor levels represented in the legend (in this example, "weakly agree" and "strongly agree" would be missing).

I am not sure if this can even be done, but I am hoping some experienced person has encountered this issue before and figured out how to fix it.

Reproducible code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

#Make a dataframe
levels <-c("strongly disagree", "disagree", "weakly disagree", "no opinion",
           "weakly agree", "agree", "strongly agree","no opinion2")
df <- data.frame("name" = rep("Factor 1", 6),
                 "response" = factor(c("strongly disagree", "disagree", 
                                     "weakly disagree", "no opinion2","no opinion","agree"), 
                                      levels = levels),
                 "percentage" = c(-25, -13, -25, 6, -6, 25))

#colours for plotting
pal <- rev(brewer.pal(7, "PRGn"))
palette <- c("strongly disagree" = pal[1],"disagree" = pal[2] ,"weakly disagree" = pal[3],
             "no opinion2" = "darkgrey","no opinion" = "darkgrey","weakly agree" = pal[5], 
             "agree"= pal[6],"strongly agree"= pal[7])

#using limits, rather than breaks, means all possible response levels are represented in the plot legend
fill_limits <- c("strongly disagree", "disagree", "weakly disagree", "no opinion2",
                 "no opinion","weakly agree", "agree", "strongly agree")
#plot
ggplot(df, aes(x =name , y = percentage, fill = response)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual (values=palette, limits = levels) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  coord_flip() +
  
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.justification=c("right", "bottom"),
        legend.box.just = "right",
        legend.position ="bottom",
        legend.direction="horizontal",
        legend.text=element_text(size = 6, hjust = 0)
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "dark grey", linetype = "dashed")
```

And here is the result (you can see that legend element I would like to remove on the bottom right):

[image: Pesky extra legend label on the right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I have added a `v2` vector. Please let me know if this is what you want:

```
#Make a dataframe
levels <-c("strongly disagree", "disagree", "weakly disagree", "no opinion",
           "weakly agree", "agree", "strongly agree","no opinion2")
df <- data.frame("name" = rep("Factor 1", 6),
                 "response" = factor(c("strongly disagree", "disagree", 
                                       "weakly disagree", "no opinion2","no opinion","agree"), 
                                     levels = levels),
                 "percentage" = c(-25, -13, -25, 6, -6, 25))

#colours for plotting
pal <- rev(brewer.pal(7, "PRGn"))
palette <- c("strongly disagree" = pal[1],"disagree" = pal[2] ,"weakly disagree" = pal[3],
             "no opinion2" = "darkgrey","no opinion" = "darkgrey","weakly agree" = pal[5], 
             "agree"= pal[6],"strongly agree"= pal[7])

#using limits, rather than breaks, means all possible response levels are represented in the plot legend
fill_limits <- c("strongly disagree", "disagree", "weakly disagree", "no opinion2",
                 "no opinion","weakly agree", "agree", "strongly agree")
v2 <- c("strongly disagree", "disagree", "weakly disagree",
        "no opinion","weakly agree", "agree", "strongly agree")
#plot
ggplot(df, aes(x =name , y = percentage, fill = response)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual (values=palette, limits = levels, breaks=v2) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  coord_flip() +
  
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.justification=c("right", "bottom"),
        legend.box.just = "right",
        legend.position ="bottom",
        legend.direction="horizontal",
        legend.text=element_text(size = 6, hjust = 0)
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "dark grey", linetype = "dashed")
```

Output:

[image]